# List of match offsets into a search string BASH only (modified by OP)

Tags: bash, shell

## This file demonstrates a typical @installhook

## it does exactly the same thing as if you would have called apps/install GoFukUrself

## and this file did not exist.

## This system exists so we can copy multiple files, rather than just a single file if

## need be. Your file does not have to be a shell file, it can be any script or program.

Comment: Can you provide us with sample data and output? It helps to know what you're working with and what you want.

Comment: You may want to pick a question title that makes somewhat more sense...

Comment: Are you aware of the ability to set the "record separator" so something other than `'\n'`?

Comment: Thank you all. Very good suggestions. I moved on to something else but I am sure all of your expertise will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# where: [$] = NAME of a string var, [%] IMMEDIATE VALUE

# example:
# declare container lookfor; declare -i offset;
# .
# .
# string.find container lookfor $offset;

shopt -s extglob    # activate extended regular expression parsing.

declare result;

# offset is optional. -% = undef.
function string.find { : [$]source [$]find [%]offset

    local buffer=${!1} find=${!2} empty='';
    local -i offset=${3:-0};

    [[ $offset -eq 0 ]] || buffer=${buffer:$offset};

    [[ -n "$buffer" ]] || { result=$empty; return 1; }

    #  Matches at front of string?
    [[ "$buffer" =~ ^("$find") ]] && { result=0; return 1; }

    [[ "$buffer" =~ ^(.*|$)?("$find")(.+|$) ]] && {

        let buffer=${#BASH_REMATCH[1]}+$offset;

    } || {

        result=$empty; return 1;

    }

    result=$buffer;

}

function string.find.all { : [$]source [$]find

    local source=${!1} find=${!2} foundlist='' offset=0;

    while string.find source find $offset; do

        foundlist+="$result ";
        let offset=$result+${#find};

    done

    echo $foundlist

}
```

Comment: So when you guys are ready to become real BASH programmers .. :D lolz - just kidding, thanks for trying to help out I hope this code helps you.

Stop by my facebook page: [link](http://www.facebook.com/pages/BASH-Scripting/158945080834274) @OpenSauce @regularfry @RaffeKettler @pavium @daenyth @dmckee Thanks guys and let me know if you find any bugs. I just started writing this about three hours ago.

Do you like my mock-up function headers? lol : @null = opportunity knocking

Comment: Could really use some shared variable optimization between these two functions. passing the data back and forth plus derefrencing sounds like a headache to me. I'll need to look at the bash sources to see how these operation are actually taking place. Anyone know which file to start in for this? It would be nice if the substring ${X:N:N} deals didn't make new variables, only used the data index pointed at by that notation. Unfortunately BASH isn't very fast so that is not very likely but would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

There is:

```
echo "1,1,2,5,5,5,6,5,4,5,7" | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

`uniq -c` is the important bit here, which is what's counting the instances which appear on separate lines in its input. `sort` is required by uniq. `tr` splits the input so there's only one "word" per line.

EDIT: I may have misinterpreted. This gives you the *count* of each match, which is what the awk example you've given gives you.

Comment: I definitely was looking for the "offset" of each match in the string. I would have liked to have the information stuffed into a bash array so I could loop through it later and perfom extraction of data on an arbitrary format that follows the search key.

Comment: For instance: ever heard of string.split? The version I wanted to develop would split the data on an arbitrary length 'splitter' but would save processing by extracting only the desired search results by an index key into the array of string offsets.

Comment: Out of interest, what is your "target system?"

Comment: BusyBox on rooted android is the maximum requirement. Awk is available, and I have perl installed, but I don't like external program dependencies. Requiring the user to manually load an entire library of congress to parse a string is out of the question. It is not reasonable at all. I can program java.. Let's just say I'm not going there with this project. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by a "full match" or where you're counting your indices from, but I think you're maybe looking for the `match` function:

```
   match(s, r [, a])       Returns the position in  s  where  the  regular
                           expression  r occurs, or 0 if r is not present
```

Comment: The indice from the start of the string.

Any old random' data maybe even a \n:mycustomseperator:The Well Formatted Data I intend to snatch from the string being searched:mycustomseperator:This is the third field but I am not about to count the chars I have typed to give an example of its offset into this example.

I need a list of offsets from the start of the string where each occurance of :mycustomseperator: begins.